# Why does using a backwards pipeline operator resolve a compilation error?

Tags: f#, fscheck

The following line is accepted by the compiler:

```
input |> Prop.forAll <| fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a
```

However, when I replace the backwards pipline operator with parentheses, I receive an error:

```
input |> Prop.forAll ( fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a )
```

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       Arbitrary -> 'a     but given a
>       ('b -> 'c) -> Property     The type 'Arbitrary' does not match the type ''a -> 'b

I'm not quite sure what this error means. Why does the backwards pipeline operator compile but the parentheses doesn't?

**Appendix:**

```
module Arithmetic

let add a b =
    a + b

open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

[<Property(MaxTest=1000, QuietOnSuccess=true)>]
let ``'a + 'b equals 'b + 'a`` () =

    // Declare generators per type required for function
    let intGenerator = Arb.generate<int>

    // Map previously declared generators to a composite generator 
    // to reflect all parameter types for function
    let compositeGenerator = (intGenerator , intGenerator) ||> Gen.map2(fun a b -> a , b)

    // Pull values from our composite generator
    let input = Arb.fromGen compositeGenerator

    // Apply values as input to function
    input |> Prop.forAll <| fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a
```

Comment: You can use `Arb.generate<int*int>` and kill off `compositeGenerator` completely.

Comment: Wow, never even considered that... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Prop.forAll` function has the type `Arbitrary<'a> -> ('a -> 'b) -> Property`. This means that the *first* argument must be an `Arbitrary`, and the next argument a function `('a -> 'b)`.

When you write `input |> Prop.forAll (fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a )`, you're attempting to invoke `Prop.forAll` with `(fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a )`, which the compiler attempts to interpret as a partially applied function.

Since the first argument to `Prop.forAll` is `Arbitrary<'a>`, the compiler attempts to infer the function as an `Arbitrary`, which it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

On the second line, you have your arguments in the wrong order.

Function application has the highest precedence, so it's applied first, before everything else. The operators `<|` and `|>` get applied after that, and they have the same precedence, so the left one is applied first, and the right one is applied second. So if you consider this line:

```
x |> y <| z
```

First you apply the left pipe and get:

```
(y x) <| z
```

And after applying the right pipe, you get:

```
y x z
```

But if you consider the second line, it's the other way around:

```
x <| y (z)
```

After applying the pipe:

```
y (z) x
```

Answer (score 3):

`input` should be the first arg, so simply

```
Prop.forAll input (fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a)
```

The reason the pipeline operator works is that the forward pipe changes the affinity in the parse order.

```
input |> Prop.forAll (fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a)
~
input |> (Prop.forAll (fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a))
~
Prop.forAll (fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a) input
```

which does not compile.  The backwards pipe changes it back.

```
input |> Prop.forAll <| fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a
~
(input |> Prop.forAll) <| (fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a)
~
(Prop.forAll input) (fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a)
~
Prop.forAll input (fun (a , b) -> add a b = add b a)
```

which does.

FWIW all the pipe operators in the sample you've given seem to obfuscate things more than they help.  Piping is usually not recommended for one-liners except in the case it helps your autocompletion.